# Do the Airpods Pro change how your internal voice sounds?

Tags: headphones, airpods

This is just a question for owners of Airpods Pro. I've noticed that with regular earbuds that seal with a foam or soft plastic tip, the seal makes your internal voice sound weird. This is very jarring and makes speaking normally very difficult. This makes earbuds very uncomfortable to use for meetings/phone calls.

Apple's regular wired earbuds don't have a perfect seal, and talking with them in doesn't change the way my voice sounds to myself. This is good, but the earbuds also don't fit well in my ears and keep falling out.

I can't find anyone talking about this online, possibly because I don't know what terms to search for. I'm wondering if anyone with Airpods Pro can let me know:

1. Are you familiar with this problem? It's possible that not everyone experiences this.
2. Do the Airpods Pro have this problem, where your voice sounds different to yourself? Does this change if you use Transparency mode?

Comment: I worked in radio for 20 years as a DJ and believe me the first few years of being on the radio your voice doesn't sound like your voice. Accurate or not it is something people who don't routinely hear their own voice rarely get used to.

Comment: I've wondered this for years @SteveChambers - when you record your voice is it more accurate to what other people hear or is it completely different?  I swear this is what I think I sound like:  https://youtu.be/trwLjCfb6ik   :-}

Comment: Not to be too pedantic here. but what you hear in your head is sonically affected by your voice (coming from the vocal cords in your neck) resonating in your head. recording your voice (barring audio processing and microphone issues) is precisely what other people hear when you speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think I'm quite familiar with your problem. Sometimes it makes me stutter when speaking on the phone, and when singing it's just really inconvenient.
2. With the Airpods Pro on transparency/pass-through mode, I personally feel that it's very natural to speak or sing with the earbuds in. I think it works really well, without any delay or disturbances that would make it sound unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

No they do not - not due to plugging your ears and not due to loopback.

Both AirPods and AirPods Pro don’t loop back audio, so you don’t get any negative effects whatsoever. You have to go out of your way to loop the audio back with a tool like LoopBack to get any hint of your own vocalizations in the mix.

- https://www.rogueamoeba.com/loopback/

AirPods Pro can be even better in transparency mode if you don’t like to have any attenuation. The Pro on full isolation mode are less effective than Etymotic ER-6 and more effective than foam noise protectors in my experience in terms of external noise and less impactful to making you think your voice is different.

Comment: I believe I understood your question perfectly and have the best answer possible. No need to accept my answer - others can have a different take. I don’t think I can make the answer better, unfortunately after these edits. I get the effect you speak of with Etymotic and foam earbuds. I don’t get it with the AirPods. I contrasted the experience with them. I reinforced my belief that the Apple kit is too open to cause a big effect, but just because I don’t jam the EarPods in my ear deeply doesn’t mean others could have a different subjective experience if they jam the device too far in.